# How to run simple requests on a 100 GB SQLite file in Python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, group-by

I have a large SQLite file *(100 GB)* that I would like to explore a bit. Basically I just want to perform simple computations like `pandas.groupby`.

Unfortunately any computation is taking **ages**, even on my powerful machines which have *10 cores, 128 GBs of RAM,* etc.

What should I do? What would be the most appropriate way to explore this dataset in Python?

Comment: What is a SQL file ? Please provide more details, especially which data and code is used

Comment: SQL is a well known database format

Comment: For sure it isn't a file. Your  details are still missing and SQL isn't a database "Format"

Comment: I use sqllite3 in python to run the request, i dont have the code in front of me. The sql is indexed to speed up things. Still its taking ages. 100 gb is not that large!

Comment: Please post some code as the answer to the question you are asking depends on what your code does and how it's implemented.

Comment: For SQLLite 100GB is pretty large. However, you need to get hold of Query Plans and examine those.

Comment: If you can provide some details about the "structure" of that database you might get good answers at dba.stackexchange.com, so consider moving your question there. But without query plains or the output of explain (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) nobody will really be able to help you.

Comment: Depend of the table size, you may need to add indexes

Comment: You could always try using another database engine like PostgreSQL that might be optimized for larger data sets.

Comment: I've used SQLite for dbs up to 1GB in size, but it tends to slow down after that. I believe SQLite loads the entire file into memory (or at least it did at one point in its history). Who created this file and is it available in other formats?

Comment: thanks. Can I export the SQL file into another format without having to load it in memory? what would be a more appropriate format to run some simple tabulations on it?

Comment: @Marged - SQLite like MS Access' JET/ACE are file level databases (not server level like Oracle, SQL Server, Postgre), so databases DO exist in individual files. OP may be referring to the `.db` or `.sqlite3` file formats. But the OP should be clear as `.sql` is a textfile format for sql scripting not database.

Comment: @Parfait in the end (almost ?) all databases will store their data in one or many files, even those server based DBMS. But luckily the OP disclosed through an edit that he uses sqlite. Till then the question was simply BS because SQL was either a "file" or a "format" for him. And exactly because of the .sql file "format" I wanted clarification in order to avoid him talking of a script or even database export.

Comment: Thanks guys for the update. I confess my noobiness here. My file is a big .sql file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already evaluate the possibility to convert your SQL database to an other database (**NoSQL** database for example) ?

Assuming that you have more than 100GB of RAM on your machines, the computation may fit easy with a REDIS (http://redis.io/) database

On that point, do you think that the database conversion is an acceptable solution ?